# How to make Canvas font size match html font size?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to render text on the canvas and I'm trying to make the size of the canvas contain just the text.

Here is the code that renders the line of text on canvas with given font:

(The code is taken from bigger code):

```js
// Renderer base class is used to calculate width and height of the terminal
// based on char size
class Renderer {
    constructor(render, { color = '#cccccc', background = 'black', char = { width: 7, height: 14 }} = {}) {
        this._options = {
            background,
            color,
            char
        };
        this._render = render;
    }
    option(arg, value) {
        if (typeof arg === 'object') {
            Object.assign(this._options, arg);
        } else if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            return this._options[arg];
        } else {
            this._options[arg] = value;
        }
    }
    render() {
        const char = this.option('char');
        const lines = this._render();
        const max = Math.max(...lines.map(l => l.length));
        const width = max * char.width;
        const size = char.height;
        const height = lines.length * size;
        this.clear({ width, height, size });
        for (let line = 0; line < lines.length; ++line) {
            const text = lines[line];
            this.line(text, 0, size * line);
        }
    }
    line(text, x, y) {
        throw new Error('Renderer::line invalid Invocation');
    }
    clear({ width, height, size } = {}) { }
}

// child class is used to render the text calculated in base class on a Canvas
class CanvasRenderer extends Renderer {
    constructor(render, options = {}) {
        super(render, options);
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
    clear({ width, height, size }) {
        this.canvas.width = width;
        this.canvas.height = height;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.option('background');
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        this.ctx.font = `${size}px monospace`;
        this.ctx.textBaseline = 'hanging';
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.option('color');
    }
    line(text, x, y) {
        this.ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    }
}


var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
span.getBoundingClientRect();


var renderer = new CanvasRenderer(() => (["Hello", "World"]), {
    background: 'white',
    color: 'black',
    char: span.getBoundingClientRect()
});

document.body.appendChild(renderer.canvas);
renderer.render();
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>Some Text</p>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<br/>
```

the problem is that with the same font on canvas and HTML the size doesn't match.
And you can calculate the number of characters per line the same as you do in HTML.

My question is how can I make the font size the same as in HTML? Or maybe how can I calculate the number per line when rendering text on Canvas?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `this.ctx.font = '1rem monospace';`?

```js
// Renderer base class is used to calculate width and height of the terminal
// based on char size
class Renderer {
    constructor(render, { color = '#cccccc', background = 'black', char = { width: 7, height: 14 }} = {}) {
        this._options = {
            background,
            color,
            char
        };
        this._render = render;
    }
    option(arg, value) {
        if (typeof arg === 'object') {
            Object.assign(this._options, arg);
        } else if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            return this._options[arg];
        } else {
            this._options[arg] = value;
        }
    }
    render() {
        const char = this.option('char');
        const lines = this._render();
        const max = Math.max(...lines.map(l => l.length));
        const width = max * char.width;
        const size = char.height;
        const height = lines.length * size;
        this.clear({ width, height, size });
        for (let line = 0; line < lines.length; ++line) {
            const text = lines[line];
            this.line(text, 0, size * line);
        }
    }
    line(text, x, y) {
        throw new Error('Renderer::line invalid Invocation');
    }
    clear({ width, height, size } = {}) { }
}

// child class is used to render the text calculated in base class on a Canvas
class CanvasRenderer extends Renderer {
    constructor(render, options = {}) {
        super(render, options);
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
    clear({ width, height, size }) {
        this.canvas.width = width;
        this.canvas.height = height;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.option('background');
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        this.ctx.font = `1rem monospace`;
        this.ctx.textBaseline = 'hanging';
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.option('color');
    }
    line(text, x, y) {
        this.ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    }
}


var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
span.getBoundingClientRect();


var renderer = new CanvasRenderer(() => (["Hello", "World"]), {
    background: 'white',
    color: 'black',
    char: span.getBoundingClientRect()
});

document.body.appendChild(renderer.canvas);
renderer.render();
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>Some Text</p>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks. that solved the issue, but for my case, I needed to use `1em`, so I can change the size for the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically get the font by selecting a random paragraph element with
`window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p')).getPropertyValue("font")`:

```js
// Renderer base class is used to calculate width and height of the terminal
// based on char size
class Renderer {
    constructor(render, { color = '#cccccc', background = 'black', char = { width: 7, height: 14 }} = {}) {
        this._options = {
            background,
            color,
            char
        };
        this._render = render;
    }
    option(arg, value) {
        if (typeof arg === 'object') {
            Object.assign(this._options, arg);
        } else if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            return this._options[arg];
        } else {
            this._options[arg] = value;
        }
    }
    render() {
        const char = this.option('char');
        const lines = this._render();
        const max = Math.max(...lines.map(l => l.length));
        const width = max * char.width;
        const size = char.height;
        const height = lines.length * size;
        this.clear({ width, height, size });
        for (let line = 0; line < lines.length; ++line) {
            const text = lines[line];
            this.line(text, 0, size * line);
        }
    }
    line(text, x, y) {
        throw new Error('Renderer::line invalid Invocation');
    }
    clear({ width, height, size } = {}) { }
}

// child class is used to render the text calculated in base class on a Canvas
class CanvasRenderer extends Renderer {
    constructor(render, options = {}) {
        super(render, options);
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
    clear({ width, height, size }) {
        this.canvas.width = width;
        this.canvas.height = height;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.option('background');
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        this.ctx.font = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p')).getPropertyValue("font");
        this.ctx.textBaseline = 'hanging';
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.option('color');
    }
    line(text, x, y) {
        this.ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    }
}


var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
span.getBoundingClientRect();


var renderer = new CanvasRenderer(() => (["Hello", "World"]), {
    background: 'white',
    color: 'black',
    char: span.getBoundingClientRect()
});

document.body.appendChild(renderer.canvas);
renderer.render();
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>Some Text</p>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks, just realized that the height of the character is not the same as font size.